# How to sort & extract values with multiple conditions in R?

Tags: python, r, dataframe

I have a basic conditional data extraction issue. I have already written a code in Python. I am learning R; and I would like to replicate the same code in R.

I tried to put conditional arguments using which, but that doesn't seem to work. I am not yet fully versed with R syntax.

I have a dataframe with 2 columns: x and y
The idea is to extract a list of maximum 5 x-values multiplied by 2 corresponding to the maximum y-values with a condition that we will select only those values of y which are at least 0.45 times the peak y-value.

So, the algorithm will have the following steps:

1. We find the peak value of y: max_y
2. We define the threshold = 0.45 * max_y
3. We apply a filter, to get the list of all y-values that are greater than the threshold value: y_filt
4. We get a list of x-values corresponding to the y-values in step 3: x_filt
5. If the number of values in x_filt is less than or equal to 5, then our result would be the values in x_filt multiplied by 2
6. If x_filt has more than 5 values, we only select the 5 values corresponding to the 5 maximum y-values in the list. Then we multiply by 2 to get our result

Python Code

```
max_y = max(y)
max_x = x[y.argmax()]
print (max_x, max_y)

threshold = 0.45 * max_y
y_filt = y [y > threshold]
x_filt = x [y > threshold]


if len(y_filt) > 4:
    n_highest = 5
else:
    n_highest = len(y_filt)

y_filt_highest = y_filt.argsort()[-n_highest:][::-1]        
result = [x_filt[i]*2 for i in range(len(x_filt)) if i in y_filt_highest]
```

For Example Data-set

```
x           y
1          20
2           7
3           5
4          11
5           0  
6           8
7           3
8          10
9           2
10          6
11         15
12         18
13          0
14          1
15         12
```

The above code will give the following results

```
max_y = 20
max_x = 1
threshold = 9
y_filt = [20, 11, 10, 15, 18, 12]
x_filt = [1, 4, 8, 11, 12, 15]
n_highest = 5
y_filt_highest = [20, 11, 15, 18, 12]
result = [2, 8, 22, 24, 30]
```

I wish to do the same in R.

Comment: So normally in SO we expect you to do more than just ask "how do I do it?" specifically by showing "what I have tried already."  Presumably you know already how to get the maxiumum of y? And  how to get the threshold value?

Comment: You're right, of course. I am just about starting with R, and I thought it would be silly to show what I had tried, as I am sure there would be elementary mistakes. I, therefore, shared my python code instead with a reproducible example. And yes, I could only go upto step 2 in the algorithm (threshold); and then I started getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reasons that R is so powerful/easy to use for statistical work is that the built in `data.frame` is foundational. Using one here simplifies things:

```
# Create a dataframe with the toy data
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = c(20, 7, 5, 11, 0, 8, 3, 10, 2, 6))

# Refer to columns with the $ notation
max_y <- max(df$y)
max_x <- df$x[which(df$y == max_y)]

# If you want to print both values, you need to create a list with c()
print(c(max_x, max_y))
# But you could also just call the values directly, as in python
max_x
max_y

# Calculate a threshold and then create a filtered data.frame
threshold <- 0.45 * max_y
df_filt <- df[which(df$y > threshold), ]
df_filt <- df_filt[order(-df_filt$y), ]
if(nrow(df_filt) > 5){
  df_filt <- df_filt[1:5, ]
}

# Calculate the result
result <- df_filt$x * 2
# Alternatively, you may want the result to be part of your data.frame
df_filt$result <- df_filt$x*2

# Should show identical results
max_y
max_x
threshold
df_filt # Probably don't want to print a df if it is large
result
```

Of course if you really need separate vectors for `y_filt` and `x_filt`, you could create them easily after the fact:

```
y_filt <- df_filt$y
x_filt <- df_filt$x
```

Note that like `numpy.argmax`, `which(df$y == max(y))` will return multiple values if your maximum is not unique.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you kindly advise about the last part of my problem? x_filt cannot have more than 5 values. If it has, for example, 10 values; I will have to select only the 5 values corresponding to the maximum y-values.

Comment: Ah, okay, I've edited the code accordingly. I'm recommending that you just sort the dataframe by descending y values and then test the resulting dimensions.